# How to run higher google play service version apk in lower google play service suported phone

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, location-services

My android app google play service version is higher than the mobile phone google play service version. It was version '5.0.89'. But google location services are not working in my phone.

After I updated it to 8.1.0 my app location services started working fine. But I want to get this to work for lower versions too.

Can anybody help me??

Comment: I think you should to make the `google play service` version stays the same. If you use the latest one, your phone should update to the latest one also.

Comment: thank you very much @bjiang